# Cleaning Tallis Godol and Tallis Koton

Tags: tallit-gadol, tallit-katan, cleaning

According to Halacha is one allowed to give in his Tallis Godol or Kotton to a cleaners if the actual work will be done by non Jews?

Comment: what exactly is your concern halachically?

Comment: This sounds like a CYLOR….

Answer (score 9):

The [Rema OC 21:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.21.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) mentions, that some have a custom of not giving a Tallis to a non-Jewish launderer.

The [Beis Yosef (ibid.)](https://www.sefaria.org/Beit_Yosef%2C_Orach_Chaim.21.2.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) notes that he never heard of such a custom.

Rabbi Zalman of Liadi in his work [(ibid. par. 4)](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3269373/jewish/Shulchan-Aruch-Chapter-21-What-is-to-be-Done-with-Tzitzis-Detached-from-Old-Tallisos.htm#v4) posits that it is permitted to give a Tallis to a non-Jewish launderer.